# Python - changing paste behavior in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to make a small program, but I've run into troubles with pasting.

I want to be able to click text in a Text widget with the middle mouse button without it pasting anything. I have tried things like binding over it:

```
text.bind('<<Paste>>', lambda x: 'break')
```

But this only disables the keyboard Ctrl-V pasting, not the middle mouse. This makes me think that perhaps it is an X11 (I am on Debian) issue, but even if that is the case, is there a way to intercept the paste event? I would like to make it as portable as possible.

Comment: Look inside `text.tcl` which is usually in `/usr/share/tcltk8.6` on debian to see what bindings the text widget has by default. This will tell you what you need to re-bind.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433369/deleting-and-changing-a-tkinter-event-binding-in-python

Comment: Thank you! It looks like what I needed to bind over was `<<PasteSelection>>`, instead of `<<Paste>>`. This preserves the Ctrl-V pasting, but disables the middle click paste. You can post it as an answer and I'll be happy to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default bindings for the text widget are in a file called `text.tcl` which usually lives in `/usr/share/tcltk8.6` on Debian.

By examining the default bindings you can find which you want to override or [unbind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433369/deleting-and-changing-a-tkinter-event-binding-in-python). As you mentioned in your comment you found that it was the `<<PasteSelection>>` rather than the `<<Paste>>` binding that was doing what you didn't want.