# Tkinter unbind is (still) broken

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

The following code works normally until `root.unbind(seq,fid2)` which deletes both bindings. I'm running 2.7.

I've seen a fix for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433369/deleting-and-changing-a-tkinter-event-binding-in-python). It seems to work - it fixes the problem with the code below - but I feel uneasy modifying the source of Tkinter.
Anyone knows it this bug has been fixed in tkinter (Python 3)?

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
def cb1(e):
    pass
def cb2(e):
    pass
seq = "<Motion>"
print "before any bindings", root.bind(seq)
fid1 = root.bind(seq, cb1, add='+')
print "after bind cb1", root.bind(seq)
fid2 = root.bind(seq, cb2, add='+')
print "after bind cb2", root.bind(seq)
root.unbind(seq, fid1)
print "after unbind cb1", root.bind(seq)
```

Comment: Python 3.5.2 on Linux - I have the same problem.

Comment: what are you really trying to accomplish? In a couple of decades of programming with tk and tkinter I don't think I've ever found a good use case of adding multiple bindings to the same event.

Comment: Thanks to your answer to my previous question (bind_class) I don't need to do add='+' anymore! I really wanted to class-level binding. When I couldn't make it work I posted the question about bind_class but given the lack of answers to some of my older questions I started to look into other solutions that involved multiple bindings. Thanks again!