# How do I limit the number of times a key can pressed before having no response in TKinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, key-bindings

So I was working on some TKinter GUI code and I wanted to limit the keybind to the space bar so that it could only be pressed twenty times before becoming un-usable. How do I implement this(In general)?

Comment: have you tried simply incrementing a counter on each click, and changing the state of the button when the counter reaches 20?

Answer (score 1):

As [Bryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) mentions in comment, one example would be:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

c = 0

def space_event(event):
    global c
    if c < 20:
        print(c)
        c += 1


root.bind("<space>", space_event)

root.mainloop()
```

the above code was bugging me as it still runs the event function after 20 is reached, just not doing anything after that. Instead learning from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433503/7032856) I'd rather use below code, as this makes the space key no longer binded after `c >= 20`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

c = 0

def space_event(event):
    global c

    print(c)
    c += 1

    if c >= 20:
        root.unbind("<space>")

root.bind("<space>", space_event)

root.mainloop()
```