# tkinker unbind doesn't seem to unbind

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this code:

```
def on_click(event=None):
    c.unbind('<Button-1>')
    c.config(background="red")
    print ("You clicked the square")
    time.sleep(delay)
    c.config(background="green")
    c.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)
    root.update()
root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, background="green")
c.pack()
c.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)
root.mainloop()
```

And when I click the canvas while it is red (unbound) it prints "You clicked the square" when the sleep is done.

I already tried the approach here:   [Deleting and changing a tkinter event binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433369/deleting-and-changing-a-tkinter-event-binding)
but got no results because I'm still able to click the square and obtain a print from it when it's red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `unbind`, then freezing the app. While it is frozen, events continue to get added to the queue without being processed. Immediately after the sleep is finished you re-establish the binding before the queue has a chance to process the events. By the time the events are handled, the binding will have already been re-established.

As a general rule of thumb you should never call `sleep` in a GUI program, and this is one good illustration why.

If you want to cancel the binding for a short period of time and then reset it, cancel the binding and then use `after` to reset it after the given time period.

```
def on_click(event=None):
    c.unbind('<Button-1>')
    c.config(background="red")
    c.after(delay, enable_binding)

def enable_binding():
    c.config(background="green")
    c.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)
```

When you click, your function is called and you change the color and unbind the event. *Then, the event loop has a chance to process the color change and process additional events*. Once the time has elapsed, your function will be called and the event will be re-bound.

Comment: Thank you! this fixed the problem and even reduced my code, thanks for answering so fast.