# How can I pass multiple commands using Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, command

For example I have

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("650x500+0+0")
def do_it():
    print("1st function")
def do_it1():
    print("2nd function")
button = Button(root,text="Change Config", width=20, height=3, bg="#26d142",fg="#030208", command=do_it)
```

but I want it to pass 2 commands
just like

```
button = Button(root,text="Change Config", width=20, height=3, bg="#26d142",fg="#030208", command=do_it, do_it1)
```

Comment: Use `lambda :do_it(xx,xx)` or `functools.partial`.

Comment: simply create new function which runs `do_it()` and `do_it1()` and then use this function `command=new_function`

Comment: `command=lambda: (do_it(), do_it1())`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to create new function which runs both functions and use it with Button

```
def do_it():
    print("1st function")
def do_it1():
    print("2nd function")

def new_function():
    do_it()
    do_it1()

button = Button(root,text="Change Config", command=new_function)
```

---

As @acw1668 shows in comment you can write it shorter using `lambda`

```
button = tk.Button(root,text="Change Config", command=lambda:(do_it(), do_it1()))
```

but sometimes it can be less readable.

---

**EDIT:**

Using `bind(..., add="+")` you could also assign many functions to the same widget and event. It can be useful to `bind` and `unbind` one of functions but I don't know if you can keep order of functions.

It needs to get argument (`event`) in function. And it needs to define own `unbind()` because original `unbind()` doesn't work as expected and it removes all functions instead only selected one.

I got `unbid()` from [Deleting and changing a tkinter event binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433369/deleting-and-changing-a-tkinter-event-binding)

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def unbind(widget, sequence, funcid=None):
    """Unbind for this widget for event SEQUENCE the function identified with FUNCID."""

    # remove all functions
    if not funcid:
        widget.tk.call('bind', widget._w, sequence, '')
        return
    
    # get list with all functions
    func_callbacks = widget.tk.call('bind', widget._w, sequence, None).split('\n')
    # remove one function from list
    new_callbacks = [l for l in func_callbacks if l[6:6 + len(funcid)] != funcid]
    # bind again other functions
    widget.tk.call('bind', widget._w, sequence, '\n'.join(new_callbacks))
    # clear
    widget.deletecommand(funcid)

def do_it(event=None):
    print("1st function")
    unbind(button, '<Button 1>', bind_id1)
    
def do_it1(event=None):
    print("2nd function")

def new_function():
    do_it()
    do_it1()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root,text="Button 1", command=new_function)
button.pack()

button = tk.Button(root,text="Button 2", command=lambda:(do_it(), do_it1()))
button.pack()

button = tk.Button(root,text="Button 3")
button.pack()

bind_id1 = button.bind('<Button 1>', do_it, add="+")
bind_id2 = button.bind('<Button 1>', do_it1, add="+")
print(bind_id1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is not a good OOP solution. This just makes the OP's bad idea worse. If anything, they should just call `doit1` from `doit` and, if necessary, pass a flag to `doit` that determines if `doit1` should be called, at all. If you saw the assembly for what you suggested you would understand why it is not good advice. You're just jumping all over the place ... from `new_function` to `doit`, back to `new_function` to `doit1`, and back to `new_function` where it finally terminates. All that work to call 2 functions.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry you overcomplicate it.

Comment: No I didn't. You don't understand the full scope. I do, though. If anyone over-complicated it, it was you. Wrapping 2 function calls in a third function, for access, is inefficient, unnecessary and flat-out silly.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry: how does this make a bad idea worse? Arguably, this is the best solution given the OP's current implementation. This is precisely what functions are for - to call other code. This solution is clean, simple, easy to understand, easy to debug, and it works.