# tkinter: Unbind not working, even workarounds don't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I bring up here a problem, that's been there for ages, but is obviously still not solved and older workarounds don't work on my Python 3.7.2 (64-bit on Win10).
I have this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

# message box to enter a value where to set the scale to
class EnterValueBox(tk.simpledialog.Dialog):

    def body(self, master):
        self.e = tk.Entry(self, width=10)
        self.e.pack(pady=5)
        return self.e  # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        print(self.e.get())


# callback to open message box
def enterValue(event):
    EnterValueBox(root, title="Enter Value 0..100")


# create window with scale widget
root = tk.Tk()
scale = tk.Scale(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, from_=0, to=100)
scale.pack()
# unbind any button-3 events
scale.unbind("<ButtonPress-3>")
scale.unbind("<ButtonRelease-3>")
scale.unbind("<Button-3>")
# bind button-3 press event to open message box
scale.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", enterValue)

tk.mainloop()
```

It creates a window with a single scale widget. I want to bind ButtonPress-3 to open a little dialog to directly enter a new value. The code only prints that value to the shell, but the example shows, that the unbind is not working, because after printing the value, the dialog box is closed (when the user clicks OK) and then the default binding is executed, which sets the slider, where the user clicked in the trough of the slider widget.
I tried the workaround from [Deleting and changing a tkinter event binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433369/deleting-and-changing-a-tkinter-event-binding) with a PatchedScale widget (instead of the PatchedCanvas shown there), but that didn't make any difference.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are calling `unbind` on events you have not set bindings for. Are you trying to unbind the default bindings?

Answer (score 0):

The default bindings are not on the widget, they are on the widget class. Calling `unbind` on a widget for which there is no widget-specific binding won't have any effect.

If you don't want the default binding to run after your widget-specific binding, the normal technique is to have your bound function return the string `break`.

```
def enterValue(event):
    EnterValueBox(root, title="Enter Value 0..100")
    return "break"
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, this is interesting. I didn't find this in any docs, but of course it solves my problem. Thanks a lot! Just another question: How can I unbind an event globally for a widget class?

Comment: @petro4213: it is mentioned in the documentation for the `bind` method. To unbind globally you would need to use `unbind_class` and give it the tk widget class.

Comment: Thanks. Which documentation are you referring to? I'm using https://docs.python.org/ or https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html#bind but neither of them is mentioning "break" anywhere...