# Debind Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to programming (about 1 year but I'm only 10), and
I want to program a program that determines the coordinates of a clicked location. To do this, I want to bind the window with a function, determine coordinates and then cancel the binding. Anyone know how to unbind? This is my previous code:

```
from tkinter import *
GroesseX=200
GroesseY=200
Fenster=Tk()
xE=Entry(Fenster)
class Cor():
    def find_cor(self, event):
        global x,y
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        print('x={}, y={}'.format(x, y))
        self.show_cor()
    def show_cor(self):
        print("show_cor show_core called")
        Fenster.geometry(f'{GroesseX+200}x{GroesseY}')
        MinX=GroesseX-200
        #xE.place(x=MinX+20, y=GroesseY+30)
        xE.pack()
        xE.delete(0,END)
        xE.insert(0,f"x={x}, y={y}")
cor=Cor()
def click_handler(event):
    if event.num == 1:
        Fenster.bind('<Motion>', cor.find_cor)
Fenster.bind("<Button-1>",cor.find_cor)
```

In fact, I have no idea how to do that. I've searched the internet for quite a while but haven't found anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433369/deleting-and-changing-a-tkinter-event-binding

Comment: I don't believe you're 10 and I downvoted you for lying.

Comment: Why don't you believe me?

Comment: bro, now i am 11 and why? I'm just smart. Its not so difficult

Comment: and why would i lye?

Comment: that would be dumm

Answer (score 0):

You can call `bind` with an empty string as the function. That will remove the binding according to the official tk documentation:

*"If script is an empty string then the current binding for sequence is destroyed, leaving sequence unbound."*

```
def find_cor(self, event):
    ...
    Fenster.bind("<Button-1>", "")
```

However, this can cause a memory leak. The act of binding an event to a python function to an even causes a new function to be created in the internal tcl/tk interpreter. To clean that up, tkinter provides an `unbind` method. It requires a *funcid*, which is the value returned from the `bind` command.

So, to use that you must preserve the *funcid* so that you can later pass it to `unbind`:

```
class Cor():
    def find_cor(self, event):
        ...
        Fenster.unbind("<Button-1>", funcid)
    ...
...
funcid = Fenster.bind("<Button-1>",cor.find_cor)
...
```

Comment: Danke! Ich wusste nicht das das so funktioniert.